# How to get the text inside a div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to use a loop to display a horizontal bar of letters. I already did this by hardcoding it with a list of 26 div elements each with different ids and text, but would like to use a loop in this situation. I'm a bit confused on how to go about this. I'm using javascript inside html by the way. The project is using jQuery overall as well. Each letter has to be clickable. All in all, I'm making a game of hangman.

```
<div id="letters">
  for(x = 0; x<26; x++){
    <div class="letter" id=x>(text for each letter)?????</div>
  }
</div>
```

Comment: I'm unsure as to what you're doing.  what language are you using for the loop that is within the HTML.  Can we get more context?

Comment: I edited the post

Comment: *"I'm using javascript inside html by the way"* ... where did you get the idea that you can do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Javascript function to use looping here. AngularJS would be best to working with code like this.
Please check the example below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to loop from 1 to 6, to make HTML headings.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<div id="demo"></div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
var x ="", i;
for (i=1; i<=6; i++) {
    x = x + "<h" + i + ">Heading " + i + "</h" + i + ">";
}
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But what if I need each letter to be clickable?

Answer (score 0):

Lets say we hav a div with id alphabet, that we would like to fill

```
var $holder = $('#alphabet');

var alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWXYZ';
for (var i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++) {

   var letter = alphabet[i];
   $holder.append('<div id="'+ letter +'">'+ letter +'</div>');
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/mo1Ljm7r/

Clickable buttons: 
https://jsfiddle.net/mo1Ljm7r/1/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may work

```
<div id="letters"></div>
<script>
var x;
var alphabet = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z];
for(x = 0; x<26; x++) {
    var temp = document.createElement("div");
    temp.innerHtml = "<a href='something'>" + alphabet[x] + "</a>";
    document.querySelector('#letters').appendChild(temp);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want each letter to be clickable as a button, then you should create them as button elements instead of div elements.

Below is a javascript example that creates a button element for each letter beginning with "A".

Each button element has a class added to it `letter-button` that allows you to format all of your buttons the same way using CSS.

```js
let lettersDiv = document.getElementById("letters");
let aLetterAsciiCode = "A".charCodeAt(0); //ascii character code for "A". decimal value of 65

for(i = 0; i<26; i++){ 
  let letterButton = document.createElement("button");
  letterButton.className += "letter-button"; //use css to define the formatting of your letter buttons
  let letterAsciiCode = aLetterAsciiCode + i; //A-Z are sequential in Ascii
  let letter = String.fromCharCode(letterAsciiCode); //convert back to a string
  let letterContent = document.createTextNode(letter);
  letterButton.appendChild(letterContent);
  lettersDiv.appendChild(letterButton);
}
```

```css
.letter-button{
  display: inline;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin:2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="letters">
</div>
```

Comment: `charCodeAt` returns a UTF-16 code point, one or two which for a Unicode codepoint. Through many steps, assumptions and limitations, you could explain that the cases where it is also ASCII. But then you have to reverse it again to pass it to `fromCharCode`.

Answer (score 0):

Made it a form since it's a hangman game. Used `createElement()` and `appendChild()` methods and a `for` loop. I also added the capability to collect the letters picked by using `addEventListener()` method. Details are commented in Snippet.

**SNIPPET**

```js
function alphaPanel() {

    // Reference the <form>
    var gallows = document.forms[0];

    // Create a <fieldset> 
    var set = document.createElement('fieldset');

    // Make an array of 26 strings
    var alphaArray = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'];

    /* Start at 0;
    || For every loop...
    || ...Create a <label>...
    || ...Create an <input>...
    || ...Make <input> a [checkbox] type...
    || ...Assign <[check]> the value of i as indexed in alphaArray.
    || ...Add text to <label> with the value of i as indexed in alphArray.
    || ...Append <[check]> to <label>...
    || ...Append <label> to <fieldset>...
    || ...Continue doing this loop 25 more times
    || ...After the 26th loop is completed...
    || ...Append <fieldset> to <form>
    */
    for (let i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
      var label = document.createElement('label');
      var check = document.createElement('input');
      check.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
      check.value = alphaArray[i];
      label.textContent = alphaArray[i];
      label.appendChild(check);
      set.appendChild(label);
    }
    gallows.appendChild(set);
  }
  // An empty array to store the player's picks
var picked = [];

// When a change event occurs in <form> call alphaData()
gallows.addEventListener('change', alphaData, false);

/* If the node <[check]> is not...
|| ...the current node on the event chain...
|| ...then it's is the node that was clicked.
|| Store that node's value and then...
|| ...add it to the array picked.
*/
function alphaData(event) {
  if (event.target !== event.currentTarget) {
    var target = event.target;
    var pick = target.value;
    picked.push(pick);
  }
  console.log('Player has picked: ' + picked.toString());
}



// Call alphaPanel()
alphaPanel();
```

```css
input[type='checkbox'] {
  width: 3ch;
  height: 3ex;
}
label {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 3px;
  line-height: 1.6;
}
```

```html
<form id='gallows' name='gallows'></form>
```